# Is Google Image making use of comments / descriptions found in images?

Tags: google, images, search

I'm wondering whether Google (and other search engine) pay any attention to the text appearing in images such as Comments, Description, Exif, etc.

I'm wondering as I would imagine that it would be nice if a user creating a website with a CMS would be warned if the image text fields are not defined, or if defined, be shown the existing data to make sure it is proper.

However, that's a lot of work if the data is never used anyway!

What I'm after is a link to an authoritative video (with Matt for instance) or document that talks about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think Google pay attention to the texts appearing in images. It would consider the file name of the image, `alt` attribute, external anchor text and content around the image. See [this](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/114016?hl=en) link for detailed information.

Comment: I see that they say "_Don't embed important text inside images_" which is quite usual from Google. If the user cannot see, we don't see it either.